# Nginx not taking into account renewed let's encrypt certificates

Tags: ssl, nginx, renewal

I have a server running some NodeJs apps (MeteorJs to be precise) on internal ports. I use Nginx to `proxy_pass` requests that are targeting URLs to the apps.

Let's say `app_1` is running on `localhost:3000`, I would proxy_pass `app1.domain.com` to `localhost:3000` and then add firewall rule to restrict access on port 3000.

Then I add SSL on the incoming connection for `app1.domain.com` using letsencrypt. I generate certs using `certbot certonly -w /var/www/app1 -d app1.domain.com` and then set the nginx config file to use it.

Everything works flawlessly until it's time to renew the cert.

To do the renewal, I have the following cron job :

```
12 6 * * 3 /root/renew.sh
```

with the following script `/root/renew.sh` :

```
certbot renew 
service nginx reload
```

The problem I have is that upon expiration, the nginx webserver is not serving the new certificate !

So I added the following cron job :

```
30 6 * * 3 service nginx restart
```

but it still fails to refresh the certificate (which leads to error in navigators, saying connexion is not secure because of cert expiration). So I need to manually log in and reload nginx.

What is wrong in my setup ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get this solved? I can only think of nginx reload not being enough and maybe a stop start is needed. Other then that, is it an option to use MeteorUp: https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up ? It uses docker and has Lets Encrypt built in.

Comment: I haven't solved this yet, I need to take time to dive more into cron job logs... I confirm that reload is enough to take into account the new certificates when I do it manually. MeteorUp is not an option in my case but I will look how they renew the certs.

Comment: The only other thing I just thought of is that the cron job might need to run as root / sudo user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more testing, here is the answer to this issue:

Set the cron job to point to a bash script:

```
12 6 * * 3 /root/renew.sh
```

And set the bash script like this:

```
certbot renew
sleep 1m
service nginx reload
```

Note the presence of the `sleep` command which allows to wait until the renewal is done

Answer (score 3):

You can set everything in one cronjob line (modified basic setup):

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew --deploy-hook "nginx -t && systemctl restart nginx"
```

This cron job is triggered twice every day to check if certificate is getting expired in next 30 days or not. It shouldn't cause performance problems.

If it is getting expired then it will auto renew it quietly without generating output and restart NGINX to apply changes. If certificate is not getting expired then it will not perform any action.

Be aware `--deploy-hook` argument was added in certbot version 0.17, released in July 2017

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess the --deploy-hook was missing in my answer. Can you explain the begining of the crontab line ? (from "root" to "certbot") I don't get what it does. Thanks,

Comment: This is basic crontab that is set-up automatically when installing 'Certbot' 
basically it check's if certificate is getting expired in next 30 days or not. 
If it is getting expired then it will auto renew it